# Recommendations for Linux based SOAP web services server

Tags: linux

I'd like to build a SOAP server on Linux to serve a scalable number of users with database dependenet requests (read/write). Can you recommend a server stack this?

Comment: no one hosts HTTP Web Services on Linux???

Comment: Maybe your question is too vague - "scalable, database-backed SOAP server on Linux" isn't too specific. Try LAMP, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I would try a python based stack using https://fedorahosted.org/suds/